Ubuntu audio quality on MSI GF63 (Intel® 8th Gen / GeForce® GTX 10 series)
I have installed the latest version of Ubuntu on my MSI laptop, after having Windows before. The sound quality from my speakers kind of sucks in comparison to when I had Windows. It is quiet and kind of tinny. It isn't broken, it just sucks in comparison. I installed HDAjackretask, but every time I use it, it crashes and my computer does too.
Results of sudo lshw -c multimedia :


If you're comparing a Ubuntu you installed with a windows that came with your machine; you're comparing a tweaked system that was tailored by the OEM (machine builder/seller) who installed windows and tweaked it for your device strengths/weaknesses with a generic install of an OS.  If you download & install windows from microsoft (without the tweaks made by OEM) you'd likely have the same sound as Ubuntu gets.  To get the same from a self-installed OS as to what the machine sold with, you usually need to tweak it matching the hardware on your device.

You've tagged pulseaudio???   Ubuntu 24.04 uses pipewire by default; have you changed the default to use pulseaudio?

Thanks for the answer, I’m new to this. Do you have any suggestions for where to start? Like commands or software ( I’m a total noob)

@guiverc I installed it but I guess that explains why it only had a dummy output… again I’m sorry I’m totally new at this
